# AWS Assume Role STS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to access my S3 bucket daily using Python but my session expires every so often. Someone on this site advised I use an "Assumed Role" STS script to re-establish connection. I found a script that uses it and I am getting the following error. FYI, i have my credentials file in .aws folder.

```
"botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"
```

below is my code:

```
import boto3

# The calls to AWS STS AssumeRole must be signed with the access key ID
# and secret access key of an existing IAM user or by using existing temporary 
# credentials such as those from another role. (You cannot call AssumeRole 
# with the access key for the root account.) The credentials can be in 
# environment variables or in a configuration file and will be discovered 
# automatically by the boto3.client() function. For more information, see the 
# Python SDK documentation: 
# http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#client

# create an STS client object that represents a live connection to the 
# STS service
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

# Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role
# ARN and a role session name.
assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="ARNGOESHERE",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)

# From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary 
# credentials that can be used to make subsequent API calls
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']

# Use the temporary credentials that AssumeRole returns to make a 
# connection to Amazon S3  
s3_resource=boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
)

# Use the Amazon S3 resource object that is now configured with the 
# credentials to access your S3 buckets. 
for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

Comment: How are you providing credentials to your code? You need credentials to be able to assume an IAM role. You mentioned the `~/.aws/credentials` file but didn't indicate how you've actually set credentials. Do you have IAM user credentials in the `[default]` section of that file?

Comment: My credentials file doesnt have set credentials which is probably the issue. I have my own issued username/password fromy my IT department.  I thought STS gives temporary credentials and returns a dictionary with them? I usually use saml2aws login -a in powershell and enter my credentials. This populates a file in .aws folder with the token and session needed. But has you probably imagine, I cant keep doing this manually so looking for a pythonic way to get new creds or session so when my script DOES run and look inside s3 bucket without failing because of "expired" session.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the credentials emitted by saml2aws? By default it seems to store the credentials in the `saml` profile in `~/.aws/config` so you need to supply that to your application e.g. `session = boto3.Session(profile_name='saml')` and `s3_client = session.client('s3')` or supply it on the command line e.g. `AWS_PROFILE=saml python myapp.py`

Comment: @jarmod Yes, i understand to this point. Thanks for that. Makes sense. The biggest trouble I am having is that my session expires after 8 hours and have to update that credentials file again somehow.

Comment: How is that a problem? Obviously this is a security mechanism and is intended to prevent you having long-lived AWS credentials. Why is it problematic to re-authenticate and fetch new STS credentials?

Comment: @jarmod That is my whole issue...how do i re-authenticate? I usually use powershell and run command saml2aws login -a to re-ssue new credentials to the credentials file in .aws. I would have to write a powershell python script to do this then have boto3 read the creds file? Can I just get new credentials somehow with STS?

Comment: You can't get STS credentials without valid credentials. The STS credentials indicate their expiry date/time so simple refresh your saml-provided credentials before they expire and either restart your Python app or have it programmatically create a new Session object close to the expiration time of the old credentials (but after you've manually re-authenticated via saml2aws), or simply catch an expired credentials exception, discard your Session, and create a new Session (again, after you've re-authenticated and re-fetched saml2aws-based credentials).

Answer (score 0):

You will have 2 options here:

1. Create a separate user with programmatic access. This would be permanent and the credentials would not expire. Usually this is not allowed for developers in organizations for security concerns. Refer steps:
   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-access-key/
2. If you are not allowed to have a permanent access token through the above method, then you can get the token expiration duration increased from default (1 hour) to 12 hours max to skip re-running PowerShell script every hour or so. For that, you would need to modify the PowerShell script 'saml2aws' you run to get credentials.

Add the arg 'DurationSeconds' for assume_role_with_saml() method. Refer: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role_with_saml

```
response = client.assume_role_with_saml(
    RoleArn='string',
    PrincipalArn='string',
    SAMLAssertion='string',
    PolicyArns=[
        {
            'arn': 'string'
        },
    ],
    Policy='string',
    DurationSeconds=123
)
```

The max duration you can enter here would be as per max session duration setting for your role. You can view it in your AWS console at IAM>Roles>{RoleName}>Summary>MaximumSessionDuration.